# Simple Operation Long Runtime

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

```
# PerCoinStatistics.py
class PerCoinStatistics:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.nHeads = 0


    def head(self):
        self.total += 1
        self.nHeads += 1

    def tail(self):
        self.total += 1

    def getHeads(self):
        return self.nHeads

    def getTotal(self):
        return self.total

    def reset(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.nHeads = 0

# Trial.py
from PerCoinStatistics import PerCoinStatistics
import random

class Trial:

    def __init__(self, nCoins, nFlips):
        self.m_v1 = None
        self.m_vr = None
        self.m_vm = None
        self.m_nCoins = nCoins
        self.m_nFlips = nFlips


    def flip(self, stats, times):
        for i in xrange(0, times):
            r = random.randint(0, 1)
            if 0 == r:
                stats.head();
            else:
                stats.tail();

    def run(self):
        rn = random.randint(0, self.m_nCoins - 1)
        stats = PerCoinStatistics()
        self.m_vm = 1.0;
        # flips all m_nCoins m_nFlips times
        for i in xrange(0, self.m_nCoins):
            self.flip(stats, self.m_nFlips)
            p = stats.getHeads() / float(stats.getTotal())
            if p < self.m_vm:
                self.m_vm = p
            if 0 == i:
                self.m_v1 = p
            if rn == i:
                self.m_vr = p
            stats.reset()

# main.py
from Trial import Trial
import time
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

nTrials = 1000
nCoins = 10
nFlips = 1000
b = 100

Vs = np.ndarray(shape=(3,nTrials), dtype=float, order='C');

random.seed()

startTime = time.time()
for i in xrange(0, nTrials):
    t = Trial(nCoins, nFlips)
    t.run()
    Vs[0][i] = t.m_v1
    Vs[1][i] = t.m_vr
    Vs[2][i] = t.m_vm
    #print "trial #",i,"done:",t.m_v1
endTime = time.time()

print "took ",(endTime - startTime),"secs to run",nTrials,"trials"

sys.stdout.flush()

# plot histogram
plt.subplot(311)

plt.hist(Vs[0], b, facecolor='green')

plt.title('Histogram of V1')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(312)
plt.hist(Vs[1], b, facecolor='red')
plt.title('Histogram of Vr')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(313)
plt.hist(Vs[2], b, facecolor='blue')
plt.title('Histogram of Vm')
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

The code generates simple coin flipping probability statistics.  For some reason, approximately, each coin flipping (including copying the probabilities into pre-allocated numpy array) takes 2.9 microseconds (the total time excluding plotting above is ~29 seconds on my 2.93GHz machine).

Is there a better way to speed up (besides running the trial in parallel on multiple cores)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using numpy, you can use some of the functions in `np.random` to do all the samples at once.  That will be much quicker than the way you're doing it, where every function call adds overhead.

Comment: Let me give it a try.  But I thought there should be more ways to improve; otherwise, using python to do any statistical analysis would take just too long. no?

Comment: To do statistical analysis in Python you should use numpy (and other libraries based on it, like scipy).

Comment: Your `flip` function is not actually fair. `random.randint(0, 10)` returns any of the numbers between zero and ten *including both endpoints*, so there are six even values and five odd ones. Use `randrange` if you want to exclude the end point, or better yet, use something like `random.random() < 0.5` rather than messing with integers mod 2 at all.

Comment: @Blckknght yeah, I fixed it with random.randint(0,1) to avoid both mod 2 operation and floating point comparison.  thanks.

Comment: @BrenBarn you are indeed right.  I just dropped PerCoinStatistic class and just used np.random.randint(0, 2, (self.m_nCoins, self.m_nFlips)) and then iterated through and applied np.average().  It is 98% faster.  It is very amazing but counterintuitive to me as I thought allocating numpy array and then computing the probability through iteration would be slower.

Comment: by doing everything using `numpy.random` you avoid looping in python - which typically slows things down a lot. Also there is a overhead related to each time you call a function, making `flip` very slow compared to its vectorized counterpart.

Comment: @M.T I just didn't expect vectorization in python would make such a huge difference.  Time to dig up my algebra book to do more stuffs with matrices.  Thanks for the tip.